# Imul in 64-assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have this code:

```
mov rax, 0x93f3ffc2fbc7a1ce
mov rbx, 0x5862d8a05a385cbe
imul eax, ebx
```

How does imul work for 64-bit assembly? Will the overflow aex be written in the first 32 bits of rax?

Comment: It works the same way as in 32 bit mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11177137) or [x86\_64 registers rax/eax/ax/al overwriting full register contents](//stackoverflow.com/q/25455447), although I'm not sure what you mean by "overflow", or which direction you're counting bits from.  Normally the "first" bits of a register are the low bits; we number them from 0 (lsb) to 63 (msb).  PowerPC numbers from the top but x86 doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Your code [assembles](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly) to

```
0:  48 b8 ce a1 c7 fb c2    movabs rax,0x93f3ffc2fbc7a1ce
7:  ff f3 93
a:  48 bb be 5c 38 5a a0    movabs rbx,0x5862d8a05a385cbe
11: d8 62 58
14: 0f af c3                imul   eax,ebx
```

which uses the opcode `0F AF` for `imul`.  This instruction has 32-bit operand size so it only read EAX and EBX, and only writes EAX.  This [implicitly zero-extends into RAX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137), zeroing the upper 32 bits.

Unlike the 1-operand form of `imul`, the high-half of the 32x32 => 64-bit full multiply isn't written to EDX (or anywhere else like the high half of RAX); it's simply discarded or for efficiency not even calculated at all.  See the [documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul); 2-operand `imul reg, r/m32` is just like `add reg, r/m32` or `or reg, r/m32` - it doesn't do any special weird stuff.

Using `mov rax, imm64` before this 32-bit multiply is completely pointless, `mov eax,0xfbc7a1ce` would give exactly identical results.  (The `imul` doesn't destroy RBX, so the upper 32 bits of the value you put into RBX is still there if you want to read it later.  It has no effect on the `imul` instruction, though.)

Even better, `imul eax, ebx, 0xfbc7a1ce` could have avoided a `mov`.

Comment: Writing a 32-bit register (EAX) *always* zero-extends into the full 64-bit register. [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11177137).  But yes, `mov r64,imm64` to feed a 32-bit operand-size imul is totally pointless.  The multiply result isn't truncated, it was always a 32-bit multiply in the first place, only reading 32-bit inputs.  (Or did you mean the 32x32 => 64-bit multiply coming out of the HW multiplier execution unit is truncated to 32-bit since this is the 2-operand form, not `imul ebx`?  That's true)

Comment: @PeterCordes I meant the latter. I forgot about the zero-extension: thanks for the correction.

Comment: I fixed your answer for you.  Don't leave wrong info in your answer, just fix it to what it should have said in the first place.