# Printing square triangular numbers not excpected value

Tags: assembly, x86

So, I want to print a square triangular numbers, you can see at  [here](https://oeis.org/A001110).

This is code I wrote :

```
global main
extern printf

section .data
format     db "%u ", 0

section .text

main:
    mov     ecx, 8
square_triangular:
    xor     edx, edx
    mov     eax, 0
    call    print       ; just print zero in early
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, ebx
    jecxz   .done
.loop:
    call    print
    imul    eax, 34
    sub     eax, edx
    add     eax, 2
    mov     edi, eax
    add     edx, 1
    sub     edx, 1
    xchg    ebx, edx
    mov     ebx, edi
    mov     eax, eax    ; store in eax
    loop    .loop
.done:
    ret

print:
    pushad
    push    eax
    push    format
    call    printf
    add     esp, 8
    popad
    ret
```

The result correct value is iteration from `0 - 7` but at iteration `8` not correct value.

```
0 1 36 1225 41616 1413721 48024900 1631432881 3881085504
                                                  ^
                                                  |
                                         here (this is wrong)
```

So you can help me to fix this if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

`imul eax, 34` does a 32-bit multiplication and the result overflows

Comment: can you make an answer ? how to fix this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59652546/imul-in-64-assembly and you could consider using unsigned (mul) instead.